# How to fetch the value on curser movement?

Tags: asp.net

I have three textboxes on a dynamically adding rows.

The first two are for entering numbers for multiplication.
And the third is for displaying the result of multiplication.

I want the result of the multiplication to appear in the third textbox as soon as I enter the numbers in the first two textboxes, without pressing any buttons.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I quite confused about dynamically adding part since there is no code.But try this code for multiplying

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Multiply();
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Multiply();
    }

    public void Multiply()
    {
        int a, b;

        bool isAValid = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);
        bool isBValid = int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out b);

        if (isAValid && isBValid)
            textBox3.Text = (a * b).ToString();

        else
            textBox3.Text = "Invalid input";
    }
```